# Strange Razor C# to VB Syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to convert the following code so that it uses vbhtml instead of cshtml.

```
01  @{
02      Html.MobSyncfusion().Header("sfheader")
03          .Position(MobPosition.Fixed)
04          .RenderMode(RenderMode.IOS)
05          .Title(@ViewData["CurrentProduct"].ToString())
06          .IOS(ios =>
07          {
08              ios.RightButton(button =>
09              {
10                  button.ShowButton(true).Caption("Products");
11              });
12          }).Render();
13  }
```

So far I have managed to convert most of this, however the IOS section is proving difficult, I have so far been unable to find any resource on the internet that even shows the C# syntax used here.

Also the developerfusion tool is of no help, it just spat out some nonsense code I have never seen this syntax before in C#

My conversion so far:

```
01    @Code
02        With Html.MobSyncfusion().Header("sfheader")
03            .Position(MobPosition.Fixed)
04            .RenderMode(RenderMode.IOS)
05            .Title(ViewData("CurrentProduct").ToString)
06            .IOS()
07                 
08            .Render()
09        End With
10  End Code
```

This is a master layout view page, Also I am very new to MVC, so any help converting this would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: The syntax `ios => { ... }` are lambdas ([VB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx), [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks, I had never come across them before so I couldn't find any internet resource, should be easy enough to convert myself. Anyone having the same problem should read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531298.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are lambda expressions.  They look very different in VB.  Here's a set of single- and multi-line lambda expressions in C#, and then the equivalent set in VB:

C#:

```
var list = new List<string>();

list.Any(x => x.Length > 5);

list.Any(x => 
{
    return x.Length > 5;
});

list.ForEach(x => Debug.Print(x));

list.ForEach(x => 
{
    Debug.Print(x);
});
```

VB:

```
Dim list = New List(Of String)

list.Any(Function(x) x.Length > 5)

list.Any(Function(x)
             Return x.Length > 5
         End Function)

list.ForEach(Sub(x) Debug.Print(x))

list.ForEach(Sub(x)
                 Debug.Print(x)
             End Sub)
```

For more details, have a look at these links:

[Lambda Expressions (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx)

[How to: Create a Lambda Expression (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531298.aspx)

Comment: Thanks very much, this should definitely help.